# windows phone reviews on store

Tags: windows-phone

to get windows phone reviews i use http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us however that only brings me reviews of people with en-us as their locale. but if a user is en-bb say, it doesn't bring it.I have to to enter http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb to see it how can i get all reviews in one link..rather then going all over every locale

care to elaborate and help me on this issue please

Comment: Use http://dev.windows.com/

Comment: http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/goal-com/bb316f94-8f2d-46e2-88d4-33b353638c5d how can i see that on dev.windows

Comment: If you are the publisher of the app, just log in to your Dev Center account, go to the app in Apps section and there is Reviews tab.

Answer (score 0):

Every App is localized for the user . Imagine if my application is for India and US , and my present location is US , The app will only show the reviews made by the US user for my app from the Store.

To see the consolidated data , use your dashboard. It gives reviews about all the apps worldwide and you can even select the country where you want to see the review.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Dev Center](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/dev-center/2d3063c2-4b29-4e69-9c03-50b67b0e6aec) official app in the store.

You can use it to track all the reviews.